# Basemap Returns a Blank Map

Tags: python, visualization, arcgis, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to animate a heat map of some information regarding geographic locations in Pittsburgh using matplotlib and basemap in Python 3.  Right now I'm having issues getting basemap to use ARCGis imagery as the background. The following code only produces a blue square

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


m =Basemap(llcrnrlon=40.361369,llcrnrlat=-80.0955278,
urcrnrlon=40.501368,urcrnrlat=-79.865723,epsg=2272)

m.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D', xpixels=7000,dpi=96,verbose=True)
```

I've pulled down and run several examples from the internet about how to use arcgis images with basemap and they have run so I'm pretty sure its not a connection issue.  I've tried several different projections and EPSG's including the world and US EPSGs, but no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here. any updates regarding new way of plotting the map from server

Answer (score 3):

You have the longitudes and latitudes mixed up ([see here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2272/)):

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = Basemap(
    llcrnrlat=40.361369, llcrnrlon=-80.0955278,
    urcrnrlat=40.501368, urcrnrlon=-79.865723,
    epsg = 2272
)
m.arcgisimage(service='ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D', xpixels=7000, verbose=True)
plt.show()
```

produces this image:

[image: the final picture]

Comment: Kuhn. Recently my machine cant plot all the map in map service. Any idea what is going on now? any format plotting changes now?